# How to get single value from second table if data exists else from first table?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. **I want to get the latest updated_product_id if exists in second table  else product_id** from first table. 
I have first table sr_client_products

```
id | product_id| client_id
1  | 1         | 1
```

and second table sr_client_product_updates

```
id | product_id| updated_product_id | client_product_id| updated_date
1  | 1         | 2                  | 1                | 2016-02-03 
2  | 2         | 4                  | 1                | 2016-06-07
```

**Expected Output: Single row column

```
updated_product_id = 4 as of updated_date
```

and if second table sr_client_product_updates has no value then

```
product_id = 1 from first table
```

.**
Till now query

```
SELECT
if(ProductUpdate.updated_product_id = '',
(select ClientProduct.product_id from sr_client_products ClientProduct where ClientProduct.client_id=1),
ProductUpdate.updated_product_id)
as product_id
from sr_client_product_updates ProductUpdate where ProductUpdate.client_product_id=1 order by ProductUpdate.updated_date DESC limit 1
```

The problem with the above query is it shows data if value exists in second table else returns empty and I think the problem is with where query also
Output:
product_id = 4 if data exists in second table
else 
product_id =1 if second table is empty

Edited Query:

```
SELECT
if(count(*) = 0,
(select ClientProduct.product_id from sr_client_products ClientProduct where ClientProduct.client_id=1),
ProductUpdate.updated_product_id)
as product_id
from sr_client_product_updates ProductUpdate 
where ProductUpdate.client_product_id=1 
order by ProductUpdate.updated_date DESC limit 0,100
```

**SOLUTION As GIVEN BY @Philipp**

```
    SELECT
    COALESCE (
        sr_client_product_updates.updated_product_id,
        sr_client_products.product_id
    ) AS id
FROM
    sr_client_products
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        MAX(updated_date) AS update_date,
        client_product_id
    FROM
        sr_client_product_updates
    GROUP BY
        client_product_id
) AS lastUpdate ON lastUpdate.client_product_id = sr_client_products.id
LEFT JOIN sr_client_product_updates ON sr_client_product_updates.client_product_id = lastUpdate.client_product_id
AND sr_client_product_updates.updated_date = lastUpdate.update_date where sr_client_products.id=1
```

Comment: What is your expected result for this sample data?

Comment: product_id = 4 if data exists in second table
else 
product_id =1 if second table is empty

Comment: need some clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    COALESCE (
        sr_client_product_updates.updated_product_id,
        sr_client_products.product_id
    ) AS id
FROM
    sr_client_products
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        MAX(updated_date) AS update_date,
        client_product_id
    FROM
        sr_client_product_updates
    GROUP BY
        client_product_id
) AS lastUpdate ON lastUpdate.client_product_id = sr_client_products.client_product_id
LEFT JOIN sr_client_product_updates ON sr_client_product_updates.client_product_id = lastUpdate.client_product_id
AND sr_client_product_updates.updated_date = lastUpdate.update_date
```

Returns the updated product_id if there is one corresponding to the actual product_id. If there is no updated id, it returns the product_id.

Though I am not sure which columns you need to use for the join, product_id would be the obvious choice but your example makes it a little weird. So you might need to fix the `ON` clause.

[Fiddle for example data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55e593/1)

[Fiddle for empty second table](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9693/1)

Comment: LEFT JOIN sr_client_product_updates ON sr_client_product_updates.client_product_id = sr_client_products.id
should be this. and to use limit i need to add select statement in place of sr_client_product_updates.client_product_id. There is no relation with product_Id of the tables,

Comment: Alright, I think I got it. I didn't realise both entries in the second table belong to the same row in the first table. This query will get you the most recently updated id, or the original id if there were no updates

Comment: Its returning multiple columns and does not work if second table data is empty.

Comment: That query can not return more than one column, it will only return `id`. When the second table is empty it returns 1 as `id`, adding a sqlfiddle to the answer

Comment: You do have to add a `where` clause though, if you only need specific rows

Comment: I tried with this, there is no data for id 2 in sr_client_product_updates,still shows value
"where sr_client_products.client_id = 2" I have edited sr_client_product_updates since id cannot be same it was 1 for both. Still not desired result can be found. I want output to be updted_product_id=4

Comment: Can you adjust the fiddle so it fits the scenario you tried and give me the link? Also you should edit your question and add more example data and the result you want to have, it really is hard to follow if you have to pick the numbers out of sentences, so some kind of table to illustrate it would be nice

Comment: for second table not empty
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/308d09/2

Fiddle for empty data
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39fb4/1

but on my machine the query results different

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/113b1/1 Fiddle for both data
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f51d4 Fiddle for empty second data
Its the exact table and data of my project. its not workin in fiddle.

Comment: Ajusted the query to use `client_product_id` for the join. But somehow sqlfiddle seems to be acting strangely, even with other examples.

Comment: EDIT: AS lastUpdate ON lastUpdate.client_product_id = sr_client_products.id in place of
AS lastUpdate ON lastUpdate.client_product_id = sr_client_products.client_product_id
WORKS FINE. Thank you. I will update with solution

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your really want to do, but try this:

```
select coalesce(t2.updated_product_id, t1.product_id) as product_id
from sr_client_product_updates t1
left join sr_client_products t2
on t1.client_product_id = t2.client_id
where t1.client_product_id = 1
```

Comment: can is ask you what does the funtion   "coalesce"

Comment: @Charif [`coalesce`](https://www.google.com.tw/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjm2MDHgYTOAhUBk5QKHaWzChcQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3resource.com%2Fmysql%2Fcomparision-functions-and-operators%2Fcoalesce-function.php&usg=AFQjCNGu1CuFT46SRnF3i6RQh_UMYbefSg&sig2=bf56zrECoYCMgB88UTO9Hg)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in the if statement you query will not return '' if the value doesn't exit it return empty result so use count(*) it return always a value even when the result is empty

```
SELECT
    if(count(*) = 0,
    (select ClientProduct.product_id from sr_client_products ClientProduct where ClientProduct.client_id=1),
    ProductUpdate.updated_product_id) as product_id
FROM 
    sr_client_product_updates ProductUpdate 
WHERE
    ProductUpdate.client_product_id = 1 
ORDER BY 
    ProductUpdate.updated_date DESC limit 1
```

Comment: It always returns the first row limit and order does not work from where query.

Comment: what should it returns ?

Comment: product_id = 4 if data exists in second table else product_id =1 if second table is empty. Your query works but the only problem is that its returning first row and the where clause order by and limit is not working.

Comment: ProductUpdate.updated_date it's not in the select and limit use two value   limit 0,100 try it

Comment: I dint get you about the updated_date. There is No effect of where clause in the query.

Comment: your query is fine the where should work check your data in your table

Comment: I have double checked it. There is data in my table. its only returning the first row. There is no effect of condition in where clause
If there is no data in second table count(*) works fine but if there is data in second table then ProductUpdate.updated_product.id from my post above works and the condition in where clause is fine

Comment: may be because of count(*)   try to add a group by ProductUpdate.id  sorry i'm not in my computer

Comment: then the problem is the count(*) it return only one field

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a simple inner join

```
SELECT sr_client_product_updates.updated_product_id 
FROM  sr_client_products
INNER JOIN sr_client_product_updates on 
      sr_client_product_updates.updated_product_id = sr_client_products.product_id;
```

Comment: This won't work since your code is for joining two tables.

Comment: The join  fo the product_id work if both the table contain the same product_id .. this i desumed by your explanation

Comment: I have update the answer  .. eventually based on you sample show also the expected resul ..